# How to install camel-milo component in Apache Karaf 4.4.3?

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, milo

I have some projects using **Apache Camel 3.21.0** running on **Apache Karaf 4.4.3** and currently need to start an OPC server there. I want to use the [camel-milo](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/milo-server-component.html) component to achieve this. However I noticed that the camel-milo feature is not available to install. So the command `feature:install camel-milo` fails saying that the feature is unknown.

I checked the [karaf camel feature list](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/karaf/apache-camel/3.21.0/apache-camel-3.21.0-features.xml) in maven repo and noticed `camel-milo` is not there at all. I tried to use the `bundle:install -s mvn:` command to manually install camel-milo from maven but this leads to a chain of dependency issues which makes no sense to manually manage. It seems the required dependencies are not automatically fetched and installed.

It seems like the camel-milo component is still actively developed and maintained. I don't understand why it does not work like other camel components? i have used several components like `camel-jdbc, camel-paho, camel-xslt, camel-http` all using the `feature:install` command.

It would be great if someone could provide or point me to a guide on how I can install and use `camel-milo` on Apache Karaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot install it, and we do not provide karaf features for stuff that does not work in OSGi or is hard to install.

Also btw camel-milo has been removed in Camel v4.

Comment: Ok understood. thanks for the info. Will have to develop the opc server externally then.